# How do i prove this? ( about permutation)

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Let $n>1$.

Let $\tau \in S_{n+1}$ and $1≦l≦n+1$.

Assume that $\tau(l)=l$.

Now, define a permutation $\mu\in S_n$ as $\mu(i)=\tau(i)$ if $i<l$ and $\mu(i)=\tau(i+1)$ if $l≦i≦n$. (If $l=n+1$, then define $\mu$ as the restricton of $\tau$ on $\{1,...,n\}$.)

How do I show that $sgn(\mu)=sgn(\tau)$?

===

Below is what I have proved, so you can use these if you need:

> $sgn(\tau\sigma)=sgn(\tau)sgn(\sigma)$
>
> $sgn(\tau)=\prod_{1≦i<j≦n}\frac{\tau(j)-\tau(i)}{j-i}$

Comment: are you sure that $\tau(l)=l$? I would rather expect $\tau(l)=n+1$ making sure the $\mu\in S_n$ does not take value $n+1$.

Comment: @drhab yes i meant $\tau(l)=l$ and $\mu$ is clearly in $S_n$. I edited my post to make it clear. I just meant "removing a fixed point $l$ of $\tau$"

Comment: Then $\mu(i)=\tau(i)=n+1$ for some $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. Does this not contradict that $\mu\in S_n$?

Comment: @drhab silly me.. I have never noticed that.. I will refomulate the question and try it again. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few equivalent definitions of the signature of a permutation. One of them is $$sgn(\tau)=(-1)^k,$$where $\tau$ can be represented as the product of $k$ transpositions. In the above case, given a representation of $\tau$ as a product of transpositions, $$\tau=t_1\cdot\ldots\cdot t_k,$$we may assume that each one of these transpositions fixes $l$, and so it is easy to adjust these transpositions and represent $\mu$ as $$\mu=t'_1\cdot\ldots\cdot t'_k,$$thus both permutations have the same signature.

As a matter of fact, this is only a consequence of a more general claim. Set$$P_l:=\{\sigma\in S_{n+1}|\sigma(l)=l\},$$ then $P_l$ is obviously a subgroup, and the map $\tau\mapsto\mu$ which is described in the question is an *isomorphism* of $P_l$ onto $S_n$.

Comment: Well it is at least not easy for me to adjust those transpositions. Would you provide more details? How are $t_1',...,t_k'$ and $t_1,...,t_k$ are related?

Comment: We may assume that every one of $t_1,\ldots,t_k$ fixes $l$. Then $t'_1,\ldots,t'_k$ are constructed in the same manner like you derived $\mu$ from $\tau$.